# Android Continuous Integration using Circleci build fails with error android ndk not configured

Tags: android, android-ndk, continuous-integration, circleci

I am trying to build my project in in Circle CI. I am getting the error as NDK not configured. I have configured the Android_ndk path in the circle.yml file. Could someone please help me to figure out the error.

```
#
# Build configuration for Circle CI
#

general:
artifacts:
    - /home/ubuntu/ECGApplication/app/build/outputs/apk/

machine:
environment:
    ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
    ANDROID_NDK_HOME: ${ANDROID_NDK}

dependencies:
pre:
  - ( sleep 5 && while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; echo y; done ) | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "tools,platform-tools,android-23,extra-google-m2repository,extra-android-m2repository,extra-android-support"
  - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-23.0.2"

test:
override:
    - (./gradlew assemble):
        timeout: 360
```

Comment: It might help if you showed more of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved by changing the OS to Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise) in the Build Environment and its working now. I Was using Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)